# Invalid preprocessor token warning message

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

I have a bunch of generated functions from a supplier's tool are required to be defined by me.
Since the inner functionality of each and every one of these functions are exactly the same, I figured I could use a macro to make my life easier.

Here is the offending warning:

```
pasting "<function_name>" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Now, I define my macro as follows:

```
#define HANDLE_FUNCTION(x)               \
  void <function_prefix>_ ## x ## (void) \
  {                                      \
    x ## _Flag = TRUE;                   \
  }
```

In my code I then write:

```
HANDLE_FUNCTION(fn1)
HANDLE_FUNCTION(fn2)
```

...and so on

Any thoughts on why this occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the second `##`, it has no use (you don't want to make one symbol of `function_name(`).